# Adjust Direction Sensitivity of Two-Finger Motions on OS X Mavericks Trackpad

Tags: macos, google-chrome, touchpad

I use two-finger swipes to both scroll up/down and go forward/back in history when using Google Chrome on OS X Mavericks. I find that frequently, when I try to scroll up/down, it actually gets interpreted as a left/right swipe; this is because I sometimes swipe somewhat diagonally. I want to basically shift the balance so that swipes at a wider range of angles are interpreted as scrolling, as opposed to history motion. How can I do this?

Comment: I just upgraded from Snow Leopard; it really feels like the sensitivity to direction has increased a lot.  Would love to see a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on OSX Mavericks and Chrome.
Disable the trackpad gesture "Swipe between pages" helped a lot.

You can find it under System Preferences -> Trackapad -> More Gestures.

It didn't fix it completely but it is much much better now.